# Column does not belong to table c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting an error when trying to create a list of objects. I am calling a web service which returns a different number of columns for certain products.

I have a class to store these values which hold all columns available, but when receiving data for products that are missing 1 column it fails with the error:

Column 'x' does not belong to table y.

Since I know column does not exist I need a replacement value if it does not exist. I have about 50 different columns so putting each one of them in an (if column exist) is something I would like to avoid!

Sample code, dprow is the Object template which holds all available columns

```
dprow.currency = row.Field<string>("currency");
dprow.categoryCode = row.Field<string>("categoryCode");
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: easy way: try-catch. 
not recommended though, but just in case you found nothing.

Answer (score 3):

This is under the assumption that your row is a DataRow, but the concept applies regardless.  You can write an extension method that will check if the column exists first:

```
public static class DataRowExtensions
{
    public static T TryGetField<T>(this DataRow row, string fieldName)
    {
        return row.Table.Columns.Contains(fieldName) ? row.Field<T>(fieldName) : default(T);
    }
}
```

Usage example: `dprow.currency = row.TryGetField<string>("currency");`

Comment: Beat me to it.  I was naming mine `GetValueOrDefault`

Answer (score 0):

Take the table you get back from the web service (in my case I'm just saying create a brand new one) and then create a dictionary with all the columns that you want to have present, and what the default value should be. If that column isn't already in the table, then add it to the table with the default value.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
Dictionary<string, object> columnDefaultValues = new Dictionary<string, object>(){
    {"currency",  "some default"},
    {"categoryCode",  "some other default"},
    {"another",  43}
};   

foreach (var keyPair in columnDefaultValues) {
    if (!dt.Columns.Contains(keyPair.Key)) {
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(keyPair.Key) { DefaultValue = keyPair.Value });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used something very similar to this to solve my problem. Created a table and did a merge of the two tables.